# Installing SpinWheelControl Cocoapod gives "the compiler is unable to type check this expression in time" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to install the SpinWheelControl Cocoapod: https://github.com/joshdhenry/SpinWheelControl using swift 5 and Xcode 10.3. Installation is fine but when I go to run, the compiler gives an error:

`"The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"`

at this line of code:

```
let nearestWedge: Int = Int(round(((currentRadians + (radiansPerWedge / 2)) + snappingPositionRadians) / radiansPerWedge))
```

This type of wheel would be really useful for me if it worked.
Are you able to get this framework running with Swift 5 or perhaps refactor that line of code so it will run?

Thank you!

Comment: did you try breaking that line into small expressions ?

Comment: you could also try typing the sub-expressions, but breaking them up would be easier to read

Comment: how would that look?

Answer (score 1):

Try to break the single long expression into small expressions.

For example :

```
let exp1 = currentRadians + (radiansPerWedge / 2)
let exp2 = (exp1 + snappingPositionRadians) / radiansPerWedge
let nearestWedge = Int(round(exp2))
```